# How to Avoid a useEffect and useCallback Dependency Loop in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on converting a React component from a class component to a functional component with hooks.

I want to get a list of group members from my database. I hold the array in component state.

`const [members, setMembers] = useState([]);`

Once the members are downloaded, I want to get each member's profile picture asynchronously.

1) The component is mounted, and the following `useEffect()` is called. Note the dependency to `getMembers`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getMembers();
}, [getMembers]);
```

2) The `useEffect` callback calls the function `getMembers()`. Note the dependency to `getMembersProfilePictures`.

```
const getMembers = useCallback(() => {
    fetchMembersFromDatabase()
        .then((data) => {
            setMembers(data);

            getMembersProfilePictures();
        })
}, [getMembersProfilePictures]);
```

3) Once the members are retrieved from the database, the `members` state is updated and  `getMembersProfilePictures()` is called. Note the dependency to `members`.

```
const getMembersProfilePictures = useCallback(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        const member = { ...members[i] };

        if (member.has_picture) {
            firebase
                .storage()
                .ref()
                .child("<childUrl>")
                .getDownloadURL()
                .then((url) => {
                    member.picture_url = url;
                    const membersCopy = [...members];
                    membersCopy[i] = member;
                    setMembers(membersCopy);
                });
        }
    }
}, [members]);
```

Because the `useEffect()` depends on `getMembers()`, `getMembers()` depends on `getMembersProfilePictures()`, and `getMembersProfilePictures()` depends on `members`, as soon as the `members` state is updated, the chain of `useCallback()`s is re-created, and the `useEffect()` is called. This becomes an infinite loop of data fetching.

My current thought is to pass the data retrieved from `fetchMembersFromDatabase()` directly to `getMembersProfilePictures()` as an argument. This removes the dependency of `members` from `getMembersProfilePictures()`, and therefore removes the infinite loop.

Ignoring listening to changes in the members list in the database and ignoring caching of members and their respective profile picture, it appears that there are no drawbacks to this solution. I am wondering what other's thoughts are to this solution. Thanks!

Comment: `getMembers` and `getMembersProfilePictures` are part of the same callback, you've separated them unnecessarily and created a dependency loop.

Comment: @Adam What do you mean by separated? Should both functions be combined into one function? If that is the case, I believe that I would still have a dependency loop.

Comment: No there wouldn't be because `getMembersProfilePictures` would no longer rely on `members` because `members` comes directly from the `fetchMembersFromDatabase` call.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. We might have proposed the same solution in different words. In my original post, I said that my current thought is to pass the members from ```fetchMembersFromDatabase``` to ```getMembersProfilePictures``` as an argument. This would be the equivalent (logically speaking) to merging the two functions together and using the ```members``` directly from the database response, thus removing the dependency to the ```members``` state. Is that what you are thinking?

Comment: There's a hundred ways to solve it - you are setting members twice so it makes it seem like you want to re-render your component as soon as you get your members and then re-render again when you have their pictures, so just separate the state (answer below).

Comment: You are exactly right! I do want to re-render each time I get a new picture so that I am not blocking the UI and the end-user gets each profile picture as fast as possible. Please see my comment on your answer.

Comment: I've got a better solution for you - create a "Member" component and let each Member component be responsible for downloading it's own picture, your "top" component should only be concerned with getting the list of members.

Comment: I actually already have a Member component, and your are absolutely right! If each Member component is responsible for its own picture, I'm no longer re-rendering the entire list of components each time a new picture comes in. Excellent solution - thanks! Please add this as a solution below so that I can accept it.

Comment: 99% of the devs try to create mini applications out of their components instead of just creating teeny-tiny, almost silly tiny components. My favourite types of components are so small they are laughable, like `OptionalThemeComponent = ({theme,children}) => theme ? <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider> : children` This is what component based development should look like - components so small that you understand everything they do in under 1 minute.

Comment: I must admit that I'm part of the 99% - thinking in terms of separation of responsibilities is the best policy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: It's become clear you're trying to do too much in one component.

What you really want to do is

1. Get your list of members and render `Member` components and then
2. Have your `Member` components download their own pictures.

The below is semi-pseudo code, take the async/await stuff with a grain of salt and do it the proper way that works for you:

```
const MemberList = ({maybeWithAProp}) => {

   const [members,setMembers] = useState([]);
   useEffect(async () => {
       setMembers((await someCallToGetMembers(maybeWithAProp));
   },[maybeWithAProp]);

   return members.map(m => <Member {...m}/>

}

const Member = ({memberId}) => {

  const [pic,setPic] = useState();

  useEffect(async () => {
     setPic(null); // you're about to download a new one, probably get rid of the old one first
     setPic((await fetchPicForMember(memberId));
  },[memberId]);

  return (...)

}
```

Original answer:

Ever consider separating your state?

```
const [members, setMembers] = useState([]);
const [membersPics,setMembersPics] = useState([]);

// run on mount only
useEffect(async () => {
  const data = await fetchMembersFromDatabase();
  setMembers(data);
,[]);

useEffect(async () => {
  const pics = await Promise.all(members.map(m => fetchProfilePic(m)));
  setMembersPics(pics);
},[members]);


return <SomeComponent members={useMemo(members.map((m,i) => ({...m,url:membersPics[i]})),[members,memberPics])}/>
```

The major issue with your original code is that you were calling `setMembers` twice, which is a big indicator that what you think is one piece of state, is probably better served as being two pieces of state.

Comment: My only concern with this approach is that I must create a mapping/pointer to map a picture to a member. Not all members will have a picture, so I would either have to hold the member's UID in the member state and the memberPic state or I would have to leave empty indices in the memberPics array in order to map by array index. This is not a memory problem with 30 members, but it would be a waste of memory or duplication of data when dealing with, say, 500 + members. Is there a more efficient way to map a picture to a member?  There is always the time/space/readability tradeoff with any code...

Comment: I like the edit! It separates responsibilities, removes the re-rendering of all members when just one picture comes in, and removes the infinite loop. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

- You are calling `fetchMembersFromDatabase()` in the `useCallback` but
  not using it as a dependency.
- You are setting `members` inside `getMembersProfilePictures()` which
  is using members as dependency. This is causing infinite loop in my
  opinion.

#### Proposed solution

1. `useEffect` without any dependency
2. `useEffect` for member and call
   the get member images function. maintain another object for member
   thumbnails.

Comment: I agree that setting ```members``` inside of ```getMembersProfilePictures()``` is what is causing the infinite loop. The ```fetchMembersFromDatabase()``` function declaration is outside of this component function, and therefore not a dependency. Clever solution - thanks!